# Open Presentation in browser and listen for presentation end event

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

does Google Slides API allow open existing presentations with UI for viewing in client browser?
I found only data analyze / manipulation methods and examples. No load UI and start.

I would like to:

- open multiple presentations in client browser
- set slide time a start first presentation
- listen to it's end event, then start another presentation

There is `<iframe>` embed method in my mind, but i don't find any way to detect presentation end.

eg. [slides.com iframe messages example](https://codepen.io/hakimel/pen/PZxbod) allows to send messages to iframe parent.

So can I use Google API to open and Start presentation?
Or is there any way to communicate embed presentation with parent?

Thank you for your answers, guys!

Comment: AFAIK, it is not available for the API but I found a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760981) that had been posted earlier this year.

Comment: You may consider creating browser extension for your purpose, see for example https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remote-for-slides/pojijacppbhikhkmegdoechbfiiibppi?hl=en